Host for Visa Famille Accompagnante (linked to Visa Passeport Talent Chercheur)?
My husband is applying for a Visa Passeport Talent Chercheur to start his position as a professor at a French University. I am applying for a Visa Famille Accompagnante as a dependent of my husband. In "Step 5: Your Contacts" of my visa application, I am asked to indicate a host person or organization. Do I have to enter my husband's Convention d'accueil from the University here? Thank you in advance.
p.s. We are both non-EU nationals currently living in another EU country, if that is relevant.
